# Having to click twice on select field to populate another select field

Tags: jquery, ajax

I am using the code below to be able to populate another select field for state/regions when choosing the corresponding country. However, in order to get the second select field to populate I have to click on the first select field twice.

I know this is a common problem with a simple solution, however many of the solutions don't help answer where I'm going wrong. Could anyone point out how to fix this?

```
    $("#country").on('click',function() {
        var country = $('#country').val();
        var dataString = 'country='+ country;
        if(country){
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "query.php",
                data: dataString,
                cache: true,
                success: function(html){
                    $('#stateregion').html('<option value="">Loading...</option>');
                    $("#stateregion").removeAttr('disabled');
                    $('#stateregion').html(html);
                    $('#area').html('<option value="">-- Select State/Region First --</option>');
                }  
            });
        } else {
                    $('#stateregion').html('<option value="">-- Select Country First --</option>');
                    $("#stateregion").attr('disabled', 'disabled');
                    $('#area').html('<option value="">-- Select State/Region First --</option>');
                    $("#area").attr('disabled', 'disabled');
        }
    });
```

Comment: @Gabriel Thanks that has worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is `#country` a `select` field? If so, use the `change` event instead of `click`.